# how to deeplink an app with url in android if url has special character

Tags: android, url, xamarin

I want my app to be opened on only one url that is in the form

```
http://www.myhost.com/#/followThis/Param1/Param2
```

this is my intent

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="myhost.com" android:scheme="http" android:path="/#/followthis" />
            <data android:host="www.myhost.com" android:scheme="http" android:path="/#/followthis" />
        </intent-filter>
```

now if i replace # with any letter say 'a' it works fine 
any way i can get this???

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the `#` in the `/#/followThis` string? http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at lollipop source, you can find out why this character is a special one:

```
// If there isn't any matching ssp, we need to match an authority.
                final ArrayList<AuthorityEntry> authorities = mDataAuthorities;
                if (authorities != null) {
                    int authMatch = matchDataAuthority(data);
                    if (authMatch >= 0) {
                        final ArrayList<PatternMatcher> paths = mDataPaths;
                        if (paths == null) {
                            match = authMatch;
                        } else if (hasDataPath(data.getPath())) {
                            match = MATCH_CATEGORY_PATH;
                        } else {
                            return NO_MATCH_DATA;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return NO_MATCH_DATA;
                    }
                }
```

hasDataPath(data.getPath()) is false, because getPath() of the Uri constructed from, for example, "http://myhost.com/#/followthis", is just "/".

It's an interesting story, because according to RFCs the part after # character is rather a FRAGMENT part, not PATH part of Uri

(https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=URI_scheme)